# How Do I Get Out of Nested Loop?

Tags: excel, vba

I need help in controlling reiteration of loops in the nested If...then statement.  How do I make sure the operation happens only once for i=5 and i=6?

```
For i = 5 To 26
    Set sht = wkbk.Sheets(i)
    sht.Cells(3, 1).Value = "'" & StrConv(inputbx, vbProperCase) & " 2017"
    If i = 5 Or 6 Then
        Cells(7, 6).End(xlToRight).EntireColumn.Select
        Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range(Selection, Selection.Offset(0, 1))
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: Your "only once for i=5 and i=6" is ambiguous.  I would guess that you mean "only when i=5 **and** when i=6", but it can also be interpreted as "only once - either when i=5 **or** when i=6 (but not for both)".  Please confirm your meaning.

Comment: If you are in an incremental loop 5 to 26 and you want to do something ONLY when i = 5 or 6 but ONLY once, it will never be when i = 6 because 5 will always trigger it first. I think you want to trigger it in both scenarios which would mean you just need `i = ` before the 6. Don't use select, check out Scotts posts for how to avoid it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

and add a new variable if you want that nested if happens only once for 5 and 6:

```
Dim to_work = true
For i = 5 To 26
    Set sht = wkbk.Sheets(i)
    sht.Cells(3, 1).Value = "'" & StrConv(inputbx, vbProperCase) & " 2017"
    If (i = 5 Or i = 6) and to_work Then
        sht.Cells(7, 6).End(xlToRight).EntireColumn.Select
        Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range(Selection, Selection.Offset(0, 1))
        to_work = false
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: If they really only want it to happen once, they can just change the `If` to be `If i = 5 Then`.

Comment: Calculation dependencies **might** require it to be performed in-loop (hard to tell from just a scrap of code), but the main point I was trying to get across is that there is no need for a new variable.

Comment: i ended up creating a separate loop for the instruction.  i decided to separate because the actions weren't related anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Change the if and make sure your are referencing the correct sheet:

```
Dim clm As Long
For i = 5 To 26
    With wkbk.Sheets(i)
        .Cells(3, 1).Value = "'" & StrConv(inputbx, vbProperCase) & " 2017"
        If i = 5 Or i = 6 Then
            clm = .Cells(7, 6).End(xlToRight).Column
            .Columns(clm).AutoFill Destination:=.Range(.Columns(clm), .Columns(clm).Offset(0, 1))
        End If
    End With
Next i
```